# Connection refused when trying to access the new Podman v2 API from a remote client

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

My goal is to try out Podman's v2 HTTP REST-based API from a different machine than the one running it. Therefore, I created a virtualbox machine (based on Arch-Linux) and installed Podman 1.9.x on it. The host system is Linux Mint. The VM's network adapter is set to bridged mode.

Inside the VM, the API service is started with:

```
$ podman system service --timeout 5000 tcp:localhost:12345
```

Inside the VM, it's also possible to access the service:

```
curl localhost:12345/images/json // returns an empty JSON-array, as expected
```

However, it's not possible to access the API from the host system:

```
Failed to connect to 192.168.178.62 port 12345: Connection refused
```

iptables on the guest system is "empty" and should not be the reason. It's possible to connect via SSH. For additional verification, I installed **lighttpd** on the guest and it's possible to access it from the host:

```
curl 192.168.178.62:80 // returns HTTP 200 -> successful
```

I'm stuck at this point. Is it a network-related problem or is Podman actively refusing connections from other systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I started the Podman API the wrong way. For external access, it should be `tcp:0.0.0.0:12345` instead of `tcp:localhost:12345`.